# How to use Laravel Auth blade pages with React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I have React application that works fine (Laravel for API). And I want to use Laravel Auth .blade.php pages for authentication on my website. Is it possible to do? I haven't found any tutorials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've actually found a solution.

In your main .blade file with element to render React code you just should add section for Auth module (`@yield('auth')`). And then you should change section name in every .blade file using in Auth module:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('auth')
```